# slick.js: slick-dot mouseover movement

Tags: pagination, slider, mousehover, slick.js

is there a way slick dots hoverable ? when I click to dots, slider is moving..this is ok, but I want when I hover to dots, slider is moving too.

how can I add this hoverable option ?

```
$('.fade').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  fade: true
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your response Asaf..I find another solution from creator of slick.js.

I share the solution below.

```
$('.slick-dots li').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).parents('.fade').slick('goTo', $(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the hover event to the slickNext & slickPrevious methods.

Here's an example, just check what class each dot has, or use the nth-of-type to refer to the dot you want:

```
$('.class-of-dot').hover(function() {
  $('.fade').slick('slickNext');
}
```

Note: I assumed you are using the latest version of slick, if not you can download the latest or comment your version number or just look up for the relevant syntax to use `slickNext` in that version